# Python - Tkinter. Why doesn't my tkinter entry connect to the last variable in the list?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a class port which has a name field. 
I then have a main window which opens up a form for entering new ports. This form has a button on the first line which when pressed adds a new port to the frame where you can enter the name of the new port etc.

The Entry box's textvariable I've connected to the last port's name in the port-list, however it will not print the correct names when I press the Print button.

If changing the line

```
MAIN_gui = MAIN_GUI(root)
```

to

```
MAIN_interface_pkg(root)
```

Then it works as I want.

It is the first attempt for me with Python and Tkinter so please have some oversight with bad coding...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Tkinter as tk
MAIN_VERSION='3.6e'

class Port:
    def __init__(self, name, mode, direction):
        self.name = tk.StringVar()
        self.name.set(name)
        self.mode= tk.StringVar()
        self.mode.set(mode)
        self.direction= tk.StringVar()
        self.direction.set(direction)

def quit():
    root.destroy()

class MAIN_GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        frame.pack(expand='0', fill='x')
        frame_buttons = tk.Frame(frame, borderwidth='1', relief='groove')
        frame_buttons.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        frame_quit = tk.Frame(frame, borderwidth='1', relief='groove')
        frame_quit.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        ################
        label = tk.Label(frame, text="MAIN Gui version "+MAIN_VERSION)
        label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        ################
        quit_button = tk.Button(frame_quit, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=root.quit)
        quit_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        intf_button = tk.Button(frame_buttons, text="Create Interface Package", command=self.intf_button_action)
        intf_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def intf_button_action(self):
        global MAIN_interface_pkg_window
        if MAIN_interface_pkg_window is None:
            MAIN_interface_pkg_window = tk.Tk()
            MAIN_interface_pkg = MAIN_INTERFACE_PKG(MAIN_interface_pkg_window)
        else:
            MAIN_interface_pkg_window.update()
            MAIN_interface_pkg_window.deiconify()

class MAIN_INTERFACE_PKG(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.ports = []
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.main_frame.pack()
        self.frame_button = tk.Frame(self.main_frame)
        self.frame_button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        self.print_button = tk.Button(self.frame_button, text="Print", fg="blue", command=self._dbg)
        self.print_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.frame_three = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, borderwidth=3, relief="groove")
        self.frame_three.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self._addport(self.frame_three)        
    def _dbg(self):
        for port in self.ports:
            print("DBG:" + str(port.name.get()) + " - " + port.mode.get())

    def _addport(self,frame):
        tmp_port = Port("name", "Two", "Input")
        self.ports.append(tmp_port)
        self.frame_addport = tk.Frame(frame)
        self.frame_addport.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        if (len(self.ports) == 1):
            self.button_portname = tk.Button(self.frame_addport, text = "[+] Port Name:", width=12, command=lambda:self._addport(frame))
            self.button_portname.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        else:
            self.label_portname = tk.Label(self.frame_addport, text = "    Port Name:", width=14)
            self.label_portname.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=4)
        self.e = tk.Entry(self.frame_addport, textvariable=self.ports[-1].name)
        self.e.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        for text in ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]:
            self.b = tk.Radiobutton(self.frame_addport, text=text,
                            variable=self.ports[-1].mode, value=text)
            self.b.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root=tk.Tk()

MAIN_interface_pkg_window = tk.Tk()
MAIN_interface_pkg = MAIN_INTERFACE_PKG(MAIN_interface_pkg_window)
MAIN_interface_pkg_window.withdraw()
MAIN_gui= MAIN_GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Tk()` twice in your code.  This results in two entirely separate Tk instances running, each with its own set of variables.  I'm not sure of the exact rules here, but evidently your `StringVar()`s are being created in a different instance than they are being used.

To create more than one window in a Tkinter application, you have to use `Toplevel()` for all but one of them.